# Django transferring data over internet very slowly

Tags: django, performance, amazon-ec2, bandwidth

I have m4.large EC2 instance setup with apache and django. Website's static files are downloaded normally (apache handles /static folder), but dynamic data generated by django is transferred extremely slowly. It can take up to 8 seconds to fetch 500kB JSON encoded string (cache hit, 2ms to generate return value on the server itself). I created a test view and it displayed the same behaviour.

```
def transfer_test(request):
    return HttpResponse("."*1000000)  # Takes 12-15 seconds to download
# Static file with the same contents downloads in less than a second
```

What could be causing this slowdown? I have no middleware set up (other than default ones). Behaviour is consistent across networks and browsers, I am the only one sending requests to the server. When running django server on local machine this does not happen.

Edit: Here is Chrome's timeline report for 512kB of data being downloaded. The data is identical.

Django sends file in just under 7 seconds, while apache sends it in less than 1.2:
[image: Django serves the file in 7 seconds]
[image: Apache serves the file in 1.2 seconds]

Comment: can you use chrome network view to get the file and show the results?

Comment: Does it work on your local development server? Try running with debug-toolbar

Comment: When you are testing this is django under load? The network log doesn't look very healthy, stalled for 200ms sounds like your server or network is overloaded.

Comment: @dkarchmer When ran locally there are no such issues. I'll see what debug-toolbar outputs

Comment: @serg No these were the only requests being sent to the server